# EPPlus issue FormulaR1C1 corrupted Excel generated

Tags: c#, epplus

I am generating an excel sheet with a set of data which includes formulas that has to be applied on columns.

Ex:

```
C2= (B2-A2)/A2, C3= (B3-A3)/A3, C101 = (B101-A101)/A101
```

These formula work fine and the excel is generated properly without any errors when I'm referring column R (id= 18), but would corrupt the excel when its changed to column where id = 399.

Here is my xml code with data. Here `ColumnId` states which column, `FieldCode` states the column topic, and `FieldCalculation` states the formula for that column.

```
  <Header>
    <RowId>1</RowId>
    <HeaderCells>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>2</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1001</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>1</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1000</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>3</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1002</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>4</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1003</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>5</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1004</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>6</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1005</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>7</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1006</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>8</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1007</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>9</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1008</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>10</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1009</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>11</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1010</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>12</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1011</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>13</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1012</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>14</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1013</FieldCode>
        <FieldCalculation>UPPER(TRIM(CONCATENATE('ST1004', 'ST1005', 'ST1006', 'ST1007, 'ST1008', 'ST1009', 'ST1010', 'ST1011', 'ST1012')))</FieldCalculation>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>15</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1030</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>400</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1041</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>401</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1043</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>399</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1045</FieldCode>
        <FieldCalculation>(ST1043-ST1041)/ST1041</FieldCalculation>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>19</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1073</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>20</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1074</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>21</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1075</FieldCode>
      </HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell>
        <ColumnId>22</ColumnId>
        <FieldCode>ST1076</FieldCode>
        <FieldCalculation>ST1073+ST1074+ST1075</FieldCalculation>
      </HeaderCell>
    </HeaderCells>
  </Header>
```

Here is the code that converts the fieldcalculation to formular1c1, replacing the header topics with column's absolute locations.

ex:

1) `UPPER(TRIM(CONCATENATE('ST1004', 'ST1005', 'ST1006', 'ST1007, 'ST1008', 'ST1009', 'ST1010', 'ST1011', 'ST1012')))` is converted to `UPPER(TRIM(CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-8],RC[-7],RC[-6],RC[-5],RC[-4],RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])))`

2) `(ST1043-ST1041)/ST1041` is converted to `(RC[2]-RC[1])/RC[1]`

3) `ST1073+ST1074+ST1075` is converted to `RC[-3]+RC[-2]+RC[-1]`

Code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the formula for the field
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="formulaString">The formula string with header topics</param>
    /// <param name="headercells">The header cells list in the excel</param>
    /// <param name="columnId">The current column id</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetFieldFormula(string fieldCalculation, List<HeaderCell> headercells, int columnId)
    {
        string[] multiArray = fieldCalculation.Split(new Char[]
        { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')','-', '_', '=', '+', '{', '}', '[', ']', ';', ':', '"', '<', '>', '?', ',', '.', '/', '~', '`', '\\',  '|'});
        foreach (string column in multiArray)
        {
            string columnname = column.Replace("'", "").Trim();
            int? machingcellId = headercells.Find(headcell => headcell.FieldCode == columnname)?.ColumnId;
            if (machingcellId > 0)
            {
                string matchingcellname = "RC[" + (machingcellId - columnId) + "]";
                fieldCalculation= Regex.Replace(fieldCalculation, column, matchingcellname);
            }
        }
        return fieldCalculation;
    }
```

Then this field formula is applied to the whole column as follows.

Here `i` is the current column id and `headerCells` object contains the deserialized xml data.

```
    fieldCalculation = if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldCalculation))
    {
        string formulaString = null;
        formulaString = GetFieldFormula(fieldCalculation, headerCells, i); 
        sheet.Cells[2, i, rowcount - 2, i].FormulaR1C1 = formulaString;                    
    }

In this example when I change ST1045 (id =399) column's id to 18, the excel is not corrupted. If I apply only one formula at a time out of these three formula, then also the excel is not corrupted. I cant find what is the exact reason for this issue. I have used the latest version of EPPlus 4.5.3.1. Please give your suggestions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by changing the excel version or by limiting the number of rows on which the formulas are applied on.

ASFAIU this issue is due to the memory consumed  when opening the excel file created from EPPlus library.

I was initially using excel 2007 and when I changed to excel 2016, the file was not corrupted.

As the application I am building should support excel 2010, I included a limit for the number of rows on which the formulas are applied on. If not the formula is applied on all the rows in a column. Then the issue is fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
ws.Cells[row,column+1].Formula = Regex.Replace(ws.Cells[row,column].Formula, @"[A-Z]+(?=\d)+", ExcelCellAddress.GetColumnLetter(column+1));
```

Changing the letter of a column by regex, which validates letter and numbers searching for cells in formulas `[A-Z]+(?=\d)+;`